# permission denied error while using docker and jupyter/scipy-notebook

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a docker container for a [Jupyter/scipy-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/scipy-notebook/)  which needs file system permissions.

I tried setting some options from the [documentation](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/common.html)

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v $ML_PATH:/home/jovyan/work -e CHOWN_HOME=yes -e CHOWN_HOME_OPTS='-R' jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

I get the following error:

```
Saving figure money_happy_scatterplot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-299e2f165cf4> in <module>
     15     plt.plot(pos_data_x, pos_data_y, "ro")
     16 plt.xlabel("GDP per capita (USD)")
---> 17 save_fig('money_happy_scatterplot')
     18 plt.show()
```

Edit: The following command worked, but I am having trouble saving files from the host.

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v $ML_PATH:/home/jovyan/work -e CHOWN_HOME=yes -e CHOWN_HOME_OPTS='-R' --user root  jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> docker run -p 8888:8888 -v $ML_PATH:/home/jovyan/work --user 1001
>   --group-add users jupyter/scipy-notebook